# Spongycastle Signature.sign() returns null

Tags: android, bouncycastle, spongycastle

Using **com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.54.0.0** on **Android 7.0**

```
  byte[] testData = "test data".getBytes("UTF_8");
  Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
  sign.initSign(privateKey);
  sign.update(testData);
  byte[] signature = sign.sign();
  assert signature != null;
```

Assert would fail occasionally.

**Any clue why/when sign() method can return null ?**

**Stacktraces:**

(1) When trying to generate CSR

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: data cannot be null
       at org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1BitString.(ASN1BitString.java:114)
       at org.spongycastle.asn1.DERBitString.(DERBitString.java:83)
       at org.spongycastle.asn1.DERBitString.(DERBitString.java:89)
       at org.spongycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder.build(PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder.java:149)
```

(2) When trying to verify test signature

```
Caused by java.security.SignatureException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSignature.engineVerify(OpenSSLSignature.java:258)
       at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1275)
       at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:719)
```

Comment: As far as I can see there are no code paths that can return null.

Comment: @JamesKPolk that's why it's so frustrated. I've attached stacktrace of observed crashes - maybe my original assumption about Signature.sign() wasn't valid and problem is elsewhere...

Comment: Ok, I'm a little confused here. The exceptions are something different, an exception won't cause `Signature.sign()` to return null.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I mean that those exceptions are caused by Signature.sign() returning null

Comment: ah, ok. Well, as I said, I read through what I thought was the relevant Bouncycastle engine code and every code path either returns a non-null array or an exception is thrown. Perhaps I didn't read the correct code, or perhaps your example is not quite accurate (I assume this is abstracted from a much larger program), or perhaps it's something more mysterious like unsafe concurrency or even a bug somewhere outside of your code.